# after installed Lets encrypt SSL site is not opening

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl, firewall, httpd

I am using apache web server on centos 7. I hosted some files, and i installed. after that site was working fine for http. Then i installed Lets encrypt SSL afte this site is not opening.
I opend port number 443 also but still issue is the same.
Please help me to get solution.

Thank you

Comment: Try running 'apachectl configtest' and see where apache is choking and edit your post with the results please

Comment: @KyleH Thanks for the response. I run this command  'apachectl configtest'. I get  Syntax OK. Please let me know Next step.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your httpd config thats in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, and /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf